ODOO 17 Obtain sorted query result for a customized report
In a crm.lead model I have 2 more attributes (columns) let's call col1 and col2.
How do I obtain 2 recordsets for each user like "select * from crm_records col1 desc limit 5" and the second "select * from crm_records col1 desc limit 5" in the same?
In the beginning, I was trying to modify _where_calc​in an abstract where I put:
query.order = f"{self._table}.{top_field} DESC"
query.limit = top_limit

to append to the original query that comes with
query = super()._where_calc(*args, **kwargs)

but:

I receive all queries I put in the domain
It is not ordered like the way I want (only if I put sort in the filter)

Thank you in advance
Claudiu

You could use the |= (pipe equal)
recordset2 = env[model].search(domain, order='x', limit=n)

recordset1 |= recordset2 

but de ordering might not be consistent
you could try obtaining the ids in each recordset and then filter by the id and the other filters you would need
records = recordset1.ids + recordset2.ids
data = env[model].search([('id', 'in', records)], order='x', limit=n)

